# On the fields of rational fractions over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Let $K$ be a field with characteristic $p>0$. Let $K^{p}=\left\{ a^{p}:a\in K\right\}$. Prove that $K^p$ is a subfield of $K$. Furthermore, if $K=\mathbb{F}_{p}\left(X\right)$ is the fields of rational fractions over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, find $K^p$ and $[K:K^p]$.

Help me prove the second part.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you computed $\mathbb F_p^p$ ? Which French mathematician have you called to your rescue? Hint: Fermi won't do because he wasn't French but he is close...

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts? This seems rather demanding; you might receive more helpful comments if you rephrase the question to include some context/details of things you've tried.

Comment: Can you find generators for $K^p$? Can you name *any* elements of it?

Comment: Have you proved that $x\mapsto x^p$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Yes. I have proved.

Comment: Here is a more generous hint than my preceding one: use Fermat to show that $a^p=a$ for $a\in \mathbb F_p$ and use the strange but easy formula $(\sum a_j X^j)^p=\sum a_j (X^p)^j$ for polynomials in $\mathbb F_p[X]$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: I can prove the first part of your comment, but I need more details for the second.

Comment: Notice that $(a+b+c+...)^p=a^p+b^p+c^p+...$ and that $a_j^p=a_j$ and that $(X^j)^p=(X^p)^j$...

Comment: Follow your notice, I uderstood that strange but easy formular. But what should I do then?

Comment: Help me. Please.