# In characteristic $p$, the field extension $k(X,Y)$ over $k(X^p,Y^p)$ has degree $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field with characteristic $p>0$, $L=k(X,Y)$ be the field of rational fractions of two variables over $k$. Let $K=k(X^p,Y^p)$.
Prove that $[L:K]=p^2$

Help me a hint to prove it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that $K \subset K(X) \subset K(X,Y) = L$.  What are the degrees of the intermediate extensions?

Comment: This is (nearly) a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573160/on-the-fields-of-rational-fractions-over-mathbbf-p) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The polynomial $f = T^p - X^p\in k(X^p,Y^p)[T]$ has the zero $X$.
Thus, the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $k(X^p,Y^p)$ is a monic non-constant divisor of $f$.

By Frobenius, $f = (T - X)^p$, so over any splitting field of $f$, the monic non-constant factors have the form $f = (T - X)^i = \sum_{j = 0}^i (-1)^{i-j} \binom{i}{j} X^{i-j} T^j$ with $i\in\{1,\ldots p\}$. Its constant term is $(-1)^i X^i$, which for $i < p$ is not contained in $k(X^p,Y^p)$. This shows that no proper divisor of $f$ is in $k(X^p,Y^p)[T]$ and therefore, $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $k(X^p,Y^p)$. So 
$$[k(X,Y^p) : k(X^p,Y^p)] = \deg(f) = p.$$

Similarly, we show that
$$[k(X,Y) : k(X,Y^p)] = p.$$

Finally
$$[k(X,Y) : k(X^p,Y^p)] = [k(X,Y) : k(X,Y^p)] \cdot [k(X,Y^p) : k(X^p,Y^p)] = p\cdot p = p^2.
$$

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain. If anything is not clear, feel fre to ask!

Comment: It's generally considered rude to downvote on this board without explaining.

Comment: @user: Of course you may, and I thank you for your honesty to let me know. But I guess you won't be surprised that I'm not happy about this. It was an advanced and interesting question and I just was in the mood of giving a detailed answer. Anyway, I hope that you don't apply double standards. There are too many cheap answers to trivial homework questions out there waiting for your downvotes!

Comment: @user: This question is comparatively advanced. Just open the profile of any very-high-rep user of your choice, and have a look on which level they earn the largest part of their reputation. I really would appreciate if you extend your "full answer to homework question" flagging activities to that field.

Comment: @user: Actually, that was the reason for me to give the answer: Because I felt that the hint in the other answer is not too helptful. Anywah, I just got this on the close-vote review queue, and you might be interested for your full-answers investigations: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573381

Answer (score 0):

Construct $k(X,Y)$ as an algebraic extension of $k(X^p, Y^p)$.

It may help keep things straight in your mind if you do a change of variable: e.g. call $X^p = U$ and $Y^p = V$.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely to me?

Comment: @chu: Can you explain more precisely exactly where you have difficulty with this problem?

Comment: I don't know what is $k(X^p,Y^p)$?

Comment: @chuyenvien94: it is the smallest subfield of $k(X,Y)$ containing $k$, $X^p$, and $Y^p$. IMO, a key aspect of this problem is coming up with a simple alternate description of this field: this is closely related to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573160/on-the-fields-of-rational-fractions-over-mathbbf-p). In fact, the solution to *this* question will be essentially the same as the solution to part 2 of that question.

Comment: But that question has not be answered yet.

Comment: I know that the two questions are related to each other. So I post them nearly