# In characteristic $p$, the field extension $k(X,Y)$ over $k(X^p,Y^p)$ is not simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field with characteristic $p>0$, $L=k(X,Y)$ be the field of rational fractions of two variables over $k$. Let $K=k(X^p,Y^p)$. Then $[L:K]=p^2$ (for a proof see [In characteristic $p$, the field extension $k(X,Y)$ over $k(X^p,Y^p)$ has degree $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573311/on-the-field-of-rational-fractions-of-two-variables-over-a-field-k)). Show that $L^{p}\subseteq K$ and $L$ is not a simple extension over $K$.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously $k^p \subseteq k\subseteq K$ and furthermore clearly $X^p\in K$ and $Y^p\in K$. Since the characteristic of our fields is $p$, the Frobenius mapping $x\mapsto x^p$ is a field homomorphism. This implies $L^p \subseteq K$.

Assume that $L = K(a)$ with $a\in L$.
Since $L^p\subseteq K$, in particular $a^p\in K$. So $a$ is a zero of $f = T^p - a^p\in K[T]$.
Thus $[L : K] \leq \deg(f) = p$. Contradiction.

Comment: @Downvoter: Please explain. If anything is not clear, feel fre to ask!

Comment: Okay I will post new question.

Comment: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573410/in-characteristic-p-the-field-extension-kx-y-over-kxp-yp-is-not-simple-con#comment1213283_573410) would be why